# .NET Core 6.0 localhost couldn't find (error 404)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a problem. I'm working on an ASP.NET Core MVC project and web pages are opening. There is no problem.

`localhost:4008/admin/user/index` is opening fine, but `localhost:4008/admin/user/login` is not opening. I couldn't find out why.

I want to create an administrator login page but it doesn't work.

I checked `Program.cs` but everything is correct. It's interesting it's not opening just 1 page is not opening. Can you tell me why?

```cs
using AspNetCoreHero.ToastNotification; 
using AspNetCoreHero.ToastNotification.Extensions; 
using CleanBlog.Data; 
using CleanBlog.Models; 
using CleanBlog.Utilities; 
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity; 
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore; 

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args); 

// Add services to the container. 
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(); builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>() .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>() .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IDbInitializeer, DbInitializeer>(); builder.Services.AddNotyf(config => { config.DurationInSeconds = 10; 

config.IsDismissable = true; 
config.Position = NotyfPosition.BottomRight; }); 

var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"); 
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString)); 

var app = builder.Build(); DataSeeding();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline. 
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment()) { 
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error"); // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts. 
    app.UseHsts(); 
} 

app.UseNotyf(); 
app.UseHttpsRedirection(); 
app.UseStaticFiles(); 
app.UseRouting(); 
app.UseAuthentication(); 
app.UseAuthorization(); 
app.MapControllerRoute( name: "area", pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, we can't tell you the exact reson.BUT here i have mentioned some general ideas,

Make sure that you have a controller named UserController and it contains an action method named Login. The method signature should be something like this:

```
    public IActionResult Login()
{
    // Your code here
}
```

Check Route Configuration:
In your Startup.cs file, check the route configuration in the Configure method. There should be a route for the Login action in the UserController. The default route configuration might look like this:

```
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Ensure that your Login action is covered by the routing configuration.

Check Authorization and Authentication:
Make sure that the Login action is not decorated with any authorization attributes that might prevent access. Also, check your authentication setup in the ConfigureServices method of Startup.cs.

Check the URL Format:
Ensure that the URL you are trying to access is correct. In your case, it should be something like localhost:4008/admin/user/login. Make sure there are no typos or incorrect casing.

Comment: Firstly, I have no Startup.cs file because I'm using .Net 7.0 SDK... And I'm adding my Program.cs codes on the below

Comment: @KadirGUR Your question says .NET 6. Are you using version 6 or version 7?

Answer (score 0):

> localhost:4008/admin/user/index is opening fine, but localhost:4008/admin/user/login is not opening. I couldn't find out why.
>
> I want to create an administrator login page but it doesn't work.
>
> I checked Program.cs but everything is correct. It's interesting it's not opening just 1 page is not opening. Can you tell me why?

Based on your scenario and description, it seems that you should have two route definition. Because,the default route might not be specific enough to capture the /login action.

The first route, "area", is a convention-based route that matches any URL with an existing area name, controller name (defaults to Home), action name (defaults to Index), and an optional ID. This route would handle most pages in the Admin area, including /admin/user/index

On the other hand, the second route, `"areaLogin"`, is more specific and explicitly captures the /login action. It specifies the User controller and the Login action within the Admin area. This ensures that the framework knows exactly where to direct requests for this specific page, preventing it from falling through to the generic pattern of the first route and potentially causing a 404 error.

So based on your existing code, you could modify your route configuration within your program.cs file, as following:

```
.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "area",
    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}",
    options: new { area = "Admin" }
)
.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "areaLogin",
    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=User}/{action=Login}/{id?}",
    options: new { area = "Admin" }
);
```

**Note:** Above configuration, defines two routes: one for the default actions and another specifically for the Login action in the UserController within the Admin area.

In addition, ensure you have a controller named UserController within the Admin area and that it contains a public action method named Login. Double-check the signature and return type of the Login method.

Apart from that, verify the exact URL you're using to access the login page. It should be `localhost:4008/admin/user/login`, not `localhost:4008/admin/user/index/login` or any other variation. Please [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-8.0#add-area-route).